# Utility application done button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, utility

For some reason, in my utility application, when I press the "done" button on the top left corner of the flipside view, nothing happens. What is the code that is supposed to return to the main view? Is it this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
```

Edit: (done method)

I know the method is being executed when the button is pressed as well; that is the weird part.

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
    NSLog(@"Done Called");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the method that gets called when the done button is pressed?

Comment: Any ideas why it doesn't work? I don't believe I have changed this at all (other than adding the NSUserDefaults part, which is commented out)

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with NSUserDefaults. Your `flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:` method must not be correctly set up is my only guess.

Comment: Oh, silly me! Thank you! Somewhere I must have accidentally deleted the '[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];' in 'flipsideViewControllerDidFinish'.... so stupid. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had deleted the self dismissModalViewController statement from my delegate method... How stupid!